# how can I match openCV camera index to linux device(/dev/videoX)?

Tags: linux, opencv, camera

I use variable cameras, so I have a camera list.

### But I can't match openCV camera index to linux device (/dev/XXX)

```
cap[i] = new VideoCapture(0); // I don't know what device(/dev/videoXX) is match index 0

while(1){
    for(i = 0; i < max_cam; i++){
        cap[i]->read(frame[i]);
    }
    .....
    usleep(33);
}
```

---

I would like to write device information of device (name, vender, ...) so help me!!
Thank to read

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with OpenCV. [Although there is a rather old feature request: http://code.opencv.org/issues/3288] But you could use udev-rules to assign device-names according to name or vendor id.

Comment: but I found that in opencv code

[file] modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp

[functon] in icvInitCapture_V4L

...
sprintf(deviceName, "/dev/video%1d", CameraNumber); 
...

but this is not access external.. 
to use that information, re-build opencv